# Printing only 1 value from the list, but there is more than one | SQL LITE PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, class

Hello im doing little project with python and sqlite3,

So i have a class YPSurvey_Final with already predefined values to connect to a database called YoungPeopleFinal.db

This is the code for the class file -

```
import sqlite3

class YPSurvey_Final:

def __init__(self, database):
    self.__databaseName = database
    self.__conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    self.__cur = self.__conn.cursor()

def getNumberOfEachPhobia(self):
    """Returns the total number of people who took the survey"""
    self.__cur.execute("SELECT Phobia, COUNT(*) FROM Phobias GROUP BY Phobia ORDER BY Phobia")
    for row in self.__cur:
        self.__phobiaList.append(row)
    return self.__phobiaList
```

my problem is that it only prints onle value from the database,(Storm,123) and there is 9 more phobias to print.

I tried using this code in a separate file and it worked Fine as intended

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('YoungPeopleFinal.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Phobia, COUNT(*) FROM Phobias GROUP BY Phobia ORDER BY Phobia")


for row in cur:
    print (row)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

So i need help to figure out the way to print all the values.

the database has all the values and 100% working and correct so its not a db fault.

This is how i call my class file

```
from YPSurvey_Final import YPSurvey_Final

def main():

base = YPSurvey_Final("YoungPeopleFinal.db")
print (base.getNumberOfEachPhobia())
main()
```

Comment: How are you calling the function and printing the phobias?

Comment: You never init __phobiaList in this snippet so it's not your full code.

Comment: I did init___phobiaList but it didnot pasted for some reason.Still not working

Comment: Adir, it didnot help.

Comment: Change to `for row in self.__cur.execute(... ).fetchall():`